# Formating bibliography with natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib, chicago-style

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
Hello, world! (\Citealt[32]{Doe2999})

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{mybib}{}

\end{document}
```

(Sorry, I don't know how to emulate mybib file.)

In the bibliography it shows:

> Doe, J. (2999). *title*. City: Publisher

Whereas, 16th edition of Chicago Manual of Style says it shoud be:

> Doe, John. 2999. *title*. City: Publisher

Is it possible to update natlib chicago definitions?

Comment: You can add the relevant bib entry to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a copy of `chicago.bst`, say `mychicago.bst`, and put it in a place where BibTeX can find it. Now make the following changes to your copy:

1. Change the function `output.year.check` as indicated to remove the parentheses around the year:

   ```
   FUNCTION {output.year.check}
   { year empty$
        { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
        { write$
           " " year * extra.label *    %% changed: removed opening parenthesis for year
          month empty$
             {}                        %% changed: removed closing parenthesis for year
             { ", " * month * }        %% changed: removed closing parenthesis for year
          if$
          mid.sentence 'output.state :=
        }
     if$
   }
   ```
2. In function `format.names` change the two lines 395, 396 from

   ```
   {s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$ 't := }
   {s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't := }
   ```

   to

   ```
   {s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, ff}" format.name$ 't := }  %% changed: full first names
   {s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't := }   %% changed: full first names
   ```

   to obtain full first names of the authors.
3. To get the period after the author's names, add `add.period$` after every occurrence of `format.authors`, e.g., in line 1013 for articles, line 1038 for books. Overall I counted twelve such occurrences.
4. Save the file, and use `mychicago` as your bibliography style.