# Getting the authors' "Lastname, Firstname" format

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, formatting

I'm getting the Bibliography in the following format:

> 1. Firstname Lastname. Article..

What should I change to get the Bibliography in the following format:

> 1. Lastname, Firstname. Article..

This is the bibtex file I'm referring to:

```
@ARTICLE{Clark2010,
  author = {Clark, Michael James and Homer, Nils and O'Connor, Brian D. and Chen,
    Zugen and Eskin, Ascia and Lee, Hane and Merriman, Barry and Nelson,
    Stanley F},
  title = {U87MG decoded: the genomic sequence of a cytogenetically aberrant
    human cancer cell line},
  journal = {PLoS genetics},
  year = {2010},
  volume = {6},
}
```

And a `.tex` MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{document}

Getting the Lastname, Firstname format \cite{Clark2010}\\

\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: The [tag:cross-referencing] tag relates to the `\label`/`\ref` mechanism, not to bibliographies.

Comment: Ok. I'll take that tag out of another question as well. Thanks

Comment: You have to edit your bst file. It is shown here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117961/formating-bibliography-with-natbib/118020#118020 and explained in Tame the BeaST http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast

Comment: You can also create your own .bst which follows your own formatting rules. The easiest way is to type `tex makebst` in a terminal, and then answer all the questions which will appear. At the end of the process tex will generate a .bst for you implementing your format, according with the answers you provided.

Answer (score 6):

If you settle for a very simple method and you don't want to deal with bibliography style files (`.bst`) this is what you can do.

If you put the separating commas into braces, BibTeX will consider them as normal text and you should obtain what you want.

So your `.bib` file should be:

```
@ARTICLE{Clark2010,
  author = {Clark{,} Michael James and Homer{,} Nils and O'Connor{,} Brian D. and Chen{,}
    Zugen and Eskin{,} Ascia and Lee{,} Hane and Merriman{,} Barry and Nelson{,}
    Stanley F},
  title = {U87MG decoded: the genomic sequence of a cytogenetically aberrant
    human cancer cell line},
  journal = {PLoS genetics},
  year = {2010},
  volume = {6},
}
```

You will obtain the same result putting into braces the authors' complete name in this way:

```
@ARTICLE{Clark2010,
  author = {{Clark, Michael James} and {Homer, Nils} and {O'Connor, Brian D.} and {Chen,
    Zugen} and {Eskin, Ascia} and {Lee, Hane} and {Merriman, Barry} and {Nelson,
    Stanley F}},
  title = {U87MG decoded: the genomic sequence of a cytogenetically aberrant
    human cancer cell line},
  journal = {PLoS genetics},
  year = {2010},
  volume = {6},
}
```